# php: if($some_var != '') vs. isset / empty

Tags: php, isset

So I am fairly new to php, but before I really had a solid understanding I picked up this habit. When checking for whether or not a `$_SESSION` / `$_POST` / `$_GET` variable was set I use this:

```
if($_SESSION['username'] != '' {
 //allow access
 header('Location: welcomefriend.php')
}
else {
 //get out
 header('Location: getoutofhereyournotwelcome.php')
}
```

I have used this in login scripts for checking if the session is set to allow access, etc. So now I know about `isset` / `empty` but I always seem to run into problems with those.

So my question is will I ever encounter a problem when using `if($some_far != '')` to check if a variable is set?

Comment: Using that is not a good check to see if a variable is set. `==` and `!=` are generally "problematic" when it comes to values; however, if a variable (or array index) is "not set" then there is *no value* to begin with, which makes it even less suitable.

Comment: if($some_far) may be enough to check set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would show notice if the variable doesnot exist, so do:

```
if( !empty($_SESSION["username"]) ) {
...
```

Comment: I have only developed on my server so I guess the notice is disabled so it has not caused a problem yet. In the future I will use `empty` because it seems to check the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - it'll throw a notice if the index doesn't exist in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if a form is submitted, but not filled out, `$_POST["value"]==""` will give you a different result from `isset($_POST["value"])`. Also, `$_POST["value"]==""` will give you an error on some servers when it is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Checking if `$_SESSION['username']` is empty without checking whether there actually is a `username` entry in the `$_SESSION` array will throw notices. It's good practice to code around them. One way to do this is something like `if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != '')`

As for `empty()` vs `!= ""`, that's personal preference. One problem you might run into is that `empty()` does not accept values, only references, so you cannot do `empty(somefunction($_SESSION['username']))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) `if( !empty( $some_far ) ) {` to check if a $_POST variable is set and not empty.

If the variable can also be empty but must be set use `if( isset( $some_far ) ) {`
With [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) the variable also must not be NULL to return true.

You also won't get a notice if the variable is not set as Martin already mentioned in his post.

Answer (score 0):

I always do the following:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != '') {
  //allow access
  header('Location: welcomefriend.php')
}
else {
  //get out
  header('Location: getoutofhereyournotwelcome.php')
}
```

Testing if the index `'username'` exists in the `$_SESSION` variable first in the if statement will mean that if the index doesn't exist then we won't continue with `$_SESSION['username'] != ''` thus never causing an error.

Comment: `if (!empty($_SESSION['username'])) {` would do the job as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering

> An associative array containing session variables available to the current script

Why not use the predefined function available? `array_key_exists`

```
if(array_key_exists('username', $_SESSION) ) {
   header('Location: welcomefriend.php');
} else {
   header('Location: getoutofhereyournotwelcome.php');
}
```